# Turning several loops into one recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this piece of code:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    int j;
    if (i%2==1) j=1;
    else j=0;
    for (; j<N; j+=2)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
        {
            int n;
            if (k%2==1) n=1;
            else n=0;
            for (; n<N; n+=2)
            {

                for (int l=0; l<N; l++)
                {
                    int o;
                    if (l%2==1) o=1;
                    else o=0;
                    for (; o<N; o+=2)
                    {

                        for(int m=0; m<N; m++)
                        {
                            int p;
                            if (m%2==1) p=1;
                            else p=0;
                            for (; p<N; p+=2)
                            {

                                if (check_full(lenta,i,j,k,n,l,o,m,p))
                                {
                                    count++;
                                    cout<<"Lenta uzsipilde: ("<<i<<","<<j<<"), "<<"("<<k<<","<<n<<"), "<<"("<<l<<","<<o<<"), "<<"("<<m<<","<<p<<"), "<<endl;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way it could be turned into recursion? Basically these loops find all possible coordinates for given problem. And if it can be converted into one small recursion, will I need to use array instead of 8 variables?

Here's what I tried to do, but it doesn't work:

```
void findBishops(){
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        int j;
        if (i%2==1) j=1; 
        for (; j<N; j+=2){
            putIntoArray(array, i, j);
            if (isFull(board, array)){
                PrintAnswer(array);
            }else{
                arrayCount = arrayCount-2;
                findBishops();
            }
            }
    }
    }
void putIntoArray(array[], i, j){
    array[arrayCount++] = i;
    array[arrayCount++] = j;
}
```

Comment: You need an else for if (i%2==1) j==1; in findBishops.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you! But it's not the problem here. In my opinion, whole function is just badly written and I'm out of luck fixing it.

Comment: Can you briefly explain your task? What you said in your question is not clear.

Comment: I want to turn these eight loops into a backtracking recursion. It needs to find 4 bishop coordinates in white spaces on chessboard and check in function `isFull` if it covers all white chessboard spaces. If not, run recursion to find other solutions. And in the meantime I though it would be better to put these coordinates into array.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recurse over the bishops rather than loop over the board:

First place one bishop, then recursively place the second, and so on until you reach the last.
The backtracking happens when you return from the recursion, and that's when you try the next alternative, *for a single bishop*, and recurse again.
Until you've run out of options - that's when you're done.

Here's a rough outline:

```
place_bishop(this_bishop)
    if this_bishop is the final bishop:
        for every possible position of this_bishop:
            see if it's a solution and handle that
    else:
        for every possible position of this_bishop:
            place_bishop(next_bishop)
```

Position-picking requires some thought in order to not locate the same solution more than once.